# When I run my bot, the `ready` event doesn't fire but the bot is online

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

When I run my bot, the `ready` event doesn't fire but the bot is online. My event handler is in the `start` method in the `Client.ts` class,
and I execute the `start` method in the `index.ts` file.

***My client class:*** ./classes/Client.ts

```
import { Client as DiscordClient, ClientOptions, Collection } from 'discord.js';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

export class Client extends DiscordClient {
    commandarray: any[] = [];
    commands: Collection<string, any> = new Collection();
    constructor (options: ClientOptions, token: string) {
        super(options);

        this.login(token);
            
        }

    async start() {
        //Event Handler
        const eventDirectories = await fs.readdirSync('./events');
        for (const dir of eventDirectories) {
            const eventFiles = await fs.readdirSync(`./events/${dir}`).filter(file => file.endsWith(".ts"));

            if (eventFiles.length <= 0) 
                return console.log("[EVENT HANDLER] - Cannot find any events!");
    
    

            for (const file of eventFiles) {
                const event = require(`../events/${dir}/${file}`);

                if (event.once) {
                    this.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, this));
                } else {
                    this.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
                }

            }
        }

        // Slash Command Handler
        const cmdDirectories = await fs.readdirSync('./commands');
        for (const dir of cmdDirectories) {
            const cmdFiles = await fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}`).filter(file => file.endsWith(".ts"));

            if (cmdFiles.length <= 0)
                return console.log("[COMMAND HANDLER] - Cannot find any commands!");

            for (const file of cmdFiles) {
                const command = require(`../commands/${dir}/${file}`)
                await this.commandarray.push(command);
                await this.commands.set(command.name, command);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

***My index.ts file:*** ./index.ts

```
import { Client } from "./classes/Client";
import { config } from "dotenv";

config();

export const client: Client = new Client({ intents: 515 }, process.env.token!);

client.start();
```

***My ready event:*** ./events/Client/ready.ts

```
import { Client } from '../../classes/Client';

export default {
    name: 'ready',
    once: true,
    async execute(client: Client) {
        await console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user?.tag}`);
        await client.application?.commands.set(client.commandarray);
    }
}
```

Edit, I fixed the first issue thanks to Rahuletto, but found a new one and have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `export default` to export the event
So, instead of using `event.<property/function>` in the handler, I should use `event.default.<property/function>`

Answer (score 1):

It's a wrong path. You should show ur path structure (file format).

I think it's `../events/Client/ready.ts`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped solve the first error, but found a new issue now.